# Оплата интеграция с кассой

Tags: laravel

Мне нужно по России делать перевод на карту или кошелек, для оплаты тарифов

Есть ли в ларавел модуль для приема платежей?

Comment: Научитесь задавать конкретные вопросы. 
Все зависит от платежной системы/региона  которую вы хотите использовать.

Comment: мне нужно по России делать перевод на карту или кошелек, для оплаты тарифов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да, есть - официальное решение https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing - работает со Stripe и Braintree

Comment: If you're only performing "one-off" charges and do not offer subscriptions, you should not use Cashier. Instead, use the Stripe and Braintree SDKs directly.

Comment: а там вроде с подписками, а с одиночными платежами не особо понятно

Comment: вообще почти все платежные системы принимают пользовательские данные на своей стороне (на своем сайте) и уже результат возвращают дергая определенный УРЛ с вашей стороны - поэтому тут особо никакие модули и не нужны - программруете контроллер который будет зачислять бабло пользователю и этот контроллер будет дергать экваринг служба банка/платежного_терминала. Выбирайте любой платежный терминал который удовлетворяет вашим потребностям и читайте их доки по интеграции - там обычно все с примерами идет - ваше задача будет только пользователю плюсануть денежки в базе.

Comment: принимать просто request во входящих данных в контроллере?

Comment: @Aslero угу - они обычто постом засылают данные о платеже - из объекта реквеста вытащите данные и обработаете

Comment: спасибо за помощь